# I want to use Proxy in my PHP code

Tags: php, sockets, proxy, whatsapp

I want to change my request ip every time so i want to use proxy.
how do i implement proxy in my below code.

thankx in advance.

```
 $Socket = fsockopen(static::WHATSAPP_HOST, static::PORT);
        if ($Socket !== false) {
            stream_set_timeout($Socket, static::TIMEOUT_SEC, static::TIMEOUT_USEC);
            $this->socket = $Socket;
            $this->eventManager()->fireConnect(
                $this->phoneNumber,
                $this->socket
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the proxy has a static ip, so your requests ip wouldn't change every time. It would just get the proxys ip instead of yours.

Still, here is an example of connecting to a proxy with fsockopen. You might have to customize the command line, depending on what you want to get/send to the server/proxy. (take a look at HTTP commands for more info)

.

**Using fsockopen with a proxy:**

```
<?php
    //URL
    $server      = '1.1.1.1'; //or url
    $server_port = '123';

    //Proxy
    $proxy      = '2.2.2.2';
    $proxy_port = 8080;

    //Open connection
    $socket = fsockopen( $proxy, $proxy_port );

    //Send command to proxy
    fputs($socket, "GET $server:$server_port HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $proxy\r\n\r\n");

    //Get data
    $data = '';
    while ( !feof($socket) ) {
        $data .= fgets( $socket );  //Save each row to $data
    }

    //Close connection
    fclose($socket);

    //Dump data
    var_dump($data); //Or whatever you want to do
?>
```